# EF Code-First cached bad table name?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have a console application that is using code first Entity Framework 4.3.1.  I created a class, a DbContext, a DbSet, and I have a database connection.

The issue is that I mispelled the table name and the program threw an error.  I changed the name in the DbSet and the system keeps throwing the same error that has the old name.

Example:

```
public DbSet<SHIPPER> SHIPPERs { get; set; }
```

This could not find the SHIPPERs table in SQL server.  No problem.  I changed it to

```
public DbSet<SHIPPER> SHIPPER { get; set; }
```

and I get **Invalid object name 'dbo.SHIPPERs'."**

I did a search in Visual Studio for SHIPPERs and nothing was returned.  What am I missing?

Note: I created another DbSet for a different table and that works.

Comment: I think the issue had to do with PluralizingTableNameConvention.  I typed the name as plural and then when I removed the 's' the Pluralizing kicked in.  My fix was to add a DataAnnotation over the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with pluralization.  Add the following code inside of your DbContext class to fix the issue:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
```